# Mock internal concrete methods

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, nunit, moq

How I should mock below lines?

```
            ABCRepository abcObj = new ABCRepository();
            var model = new NamesList
            {
                ALayoutNames = abcObj.ALayout(),
                BLayoutNames = abcObj.BLayout(),
                CLayoutNames = abcObj.CLayout(),
                DLayoutNames = abcObj.DLayout(),
                ELayoutNames = abcObj.ELayout()
            };
```

I have mocked first line with its interface like below

```
Mock<IABCRepository> _iabcrepository = new Mock<IABCRepository>();
```

But how to proceed for NamesList object?

Comment: This classes implements an interface?

Comment: Only ABCRepository class implements interface IABCRepository. NamesList not.

Comment: Do you want to use the concrete implementation of this classes on your tests? Or you want to mock it too?

Comment: Check the answer. You can mock the IABCRepository and create the model by the mocked repository functions.

Comment: ALayoutNames are functions or classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This needs a bit of refactoring. That is why I find that Unit Tests help create a better code.

So here it goes, step by step:

1. Move the ABCRepository in the constructor as an argument of your class i.e.

```
    public class ClassToTest {
        private IABCRepository abcObj;

        public ClassToTest(IABCRepository repo) {
             this.abcObj = repo;
        } 

        public DoingSomething() {
            var model = new NamesList
            {
                ALayoutNames = this.abcObj.ALayout(),
                BLayoutNames = this.abcObj.BLayout(),
                CLayoutNames = this.abcObj.CLayout(),
                DLayoutNames = this.abcObj.DLayout(),
                ELayoutNames = this.abcObj.ELayout()
            };
        }
    }
```

2. In your test you need to do two things, first setup the mock responses

```
    Mock<IABCRepository> _iabcrepository = new Mock<IABCRepository>();
    _iabcrepository.Setup(foo => foo.ALayout()).Returns(MockValue);
    _iabcrepository.Setup(foo => foo.BLayout()).Returns(MockValue);
    // etc
```

3. In your test (or init, or wherever you create the instance to be tested) now create the mock object and pass it through the constructor

```
    var classToTest = new ClassToTest(_iabcrepository.Object);
```

Now when you call the DoSomething function, the mocked repository will return the mocked values.

Comment: ALayout and BLayout are classes without an interface. You do not answer the question. What are the MockValues in your code?

Comment: What are you talking about? A Alayout is a function. MockValues are the return values of the functions which I don't know, because they are not provided.

Comment: Please read the questions and answer well before downvoting how is `this.abcObj.ALayout()` `ALayout` a class?

Comment: Hey @Althanasios, thanks. answered my question and helped with good refactoring. +1, marked as answer.

Comment: Really appreciate it.  Cheers.

Comment: Sorry @AthanasiosKataras. I'm really misunderstand the question. I tried to remove the down vote but stack overflow don't let me. "You last voted on this answer yesterday. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited."

Comment: I made some structural edits, so you can change the vote now if you want.

Comment: Removed the down vote and add an up vote as you answer the question correctly. Sorry again.